# How to return a value that was fetched inside an async completion handler?

Tags: swift, xcode

I need return image in DispatchGroup().notify
this is my code:

```
func getImage() -> UIImage? {
    guard isLoaded else { return nil }
    var image: UIImage?
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    survice.getWeatherImage(data!.list.first!.weather.first!!.icon) { uiimage in
        image = uiimage
        group.leave()
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        return image
    }
}
```

and I have an error: Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to closure result type 'Void'

Please help me return the image, I tried everything but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You are mixing asynchronous code with synchronous, I suggest watching "Meet async/await" for an alternative.

Comment: `DispatchGroup` is designed for multiple asynchronous tasks in a repeat loop. It makes no sense for a single task. And `notify` has the same behaviour as a completion handler: It has no return value.

Comment: Why do you use DispatchGroup? what are you trying to solve by having it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make an async function synchronous using `DispatchGroup`, but that's not how that API works. Please ask another question if you'd like to know more about `DispatchGroup`. For now, let's solve the issue you're having.

You can solve this in two different ways.

1. You might consider using a completion closure in the `getImage` function to pass the image back to the caller when the image is ready:

```swift
func getImage(completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    guard isLoaded else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    service.getWeatherImage(data!.list.first!.weather.first!!.icon) { image in
        completion(image)
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```swift
getImage { image in
    // Use the `image` here
}
```

Alternatively, you can write this as an `async` function (see ["Meet async/await in Swift"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/) for more information).

```
func getImage() async -> UIImage? {
    guard isLoaded else {
        return nil
    }

    let url = data!.list.first!.weather.first!!.icon
    return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        service.getWeatherImage(url) { image in
            continuation.resume(returning: image)
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```swift
let image = await getImage()
// use image
```

You might need to call the async function in a Task, if the function you're calling it from is not itself async:

```
Task {
    let image = await getImage()
    // use image
}
```